# How to load a webview in android,using mebu bar icon click

Tags: javascript, android, html

am working on an android application. I created a webview in my second activity. I have done everything as directed by the documentary, but when I click the menu icon to load the second page containing the webvew, the app crashes. Please I have to state that the first activity from which am calling the second activity, is using a webview and everything is working fine. Please is there another way of loading a webview using menu icon click. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your error log and click event code with web activity

Comment: This is the click event code "if (id == R.id.action_direction) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectionActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
         startActivity(intent);
   return true;
  }"

Answer (score 0):

If your webview is implemented perfectly, The only reason to crash your application because of intent . you need to add you activity in android manifest file . 
you can check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intents_filters.htm) .

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But the activity is added in the android manifest. The truth is that before I added the webview,the activity was loading. After adding the webview the problem started. Am not to familiar with html and JavaScript.Its there any other way of loading a webview through menu bar icon click,because the first activity is a webview and is working perfectly well

Comment: did you create the webview outside of the onCreate() method ? 
if yes , then create it in the onCreate() method . then check . 
if no , Then check the id of webview is the same as in your code . 

There are no relation between the html , css and js in webview which can crash your application . if there are any problem . then it can show an error message.